# How to group results from a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```
    <?
$proplist=array(
array(name=>"Store #1", address=>"123 Example St",      city=>"Smyrna",         state=>"GA",    zip=>"11111"),
array(name=>"Store #2", address=>"666 Anywhere Rd",     city=>"Bristol",        state=>"VA",    zip=>"33333"),
array(name=>"Store #3", address=>"123 Any Street",      city=>"Bristol",        state=>"NC",    zip=>"44444"), 
array(name=>"Store #4", address=>"111 Someplace Rd",    city=>"Atlanta",        state=>"GA",    zip=>"22222"),
);
foreach($proplist as $prop) { 
echo "{$prop["name"]} - {$prop["address"]}, {$prop["state"]} {$prop["zipcode"]}<br>" ; 
}  
?>
```

Which give me this:

Store #1 - 123 Example St, GA 
Store #2 - 666 Anywhere Rd, VA 
Store #3 - 123 Any Street, NC 
Store #4 - 111 Someplace Rd, GA

What Im trying to accomplish is:

#### GA

Store #1 - 123 Example St, GA
Store #4 - 111 Someplace Rd, GA

#### VA

Store #2 - 666 Anywhere Rd, VA

#### NC

Store #3 - 123 Any Street, NC

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
public function array_group_by($array, $key) {

    if (is_null($key)) return $array;
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $group_key = $item[$key];
        if (!array_key_exists($group_key, $result)) {
            $result[$group_key] = array();
        }
        $result[$group_key][] = $item;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

so you can call `array_group_by($proplist, 'state');` which should give you the required result as an array.

```
var_dump(array_group_by($proplist,'state');
```

should output

```
array (size=3)
  'GA' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'name' => string 'Store #1' (length=8)
          'address' => string '123 Example St' (length=14)
          'city' => string 'Smyrna' (length=6)
          'state' => string 'GA' (length=2)
          'zip' => string '11111' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'name' => string 'Store #4' (length=8)
          'address' => string '111 Someplace Rd' (length=16)
          'city' => string 'Atlanta' (length=7)
          'state' => string 'GA' (length=2)
          'zip' => string '22222' (length=5)
  'VA' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'name' => string 'Store #2' (length=8)
          'address' => string '666 Anywhere Rd' (length=15)
          'city' => string 'Bristol' (length=7)
          'state' => string 'VA' (length=2)
          'zip' => string '33333' (length=5)
  'NC' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'name' => string 'Store #3' (length=8)
          'address' => string '123 Any Street' (length=14)
          'city' => string 'Bristol' (length=7)
          'state' => string 'NC' (length=2)
          'zip' => string '44444' (length=5)
```

You can also find a working example here https://eval.in/98276

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no grouping build in functions to archive this. So the only way is to do it manually, like so:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($proplist as $data) {
  $id = $data['state'];
  if (isset($result[$id])) {
     $result[$id][] = $data;
  } else {
     $result[$id] = array($data);
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Or if you want only to sort those elements:

```
foreach ($proplist as $key => $row) {
    $states[$key]  = $row['state']; 
}
array_multisort($states, SORT_ASC, $proplist);
```